# Linking page in a div with html forms and php

Tags: php, jquery, html, hyperlink

So I have this html code

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="header">

</div>
<div id="content">
    <form method="POST" action="code.php"> 
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="name" size="50">
        <input type=submit value="Get Code">
        </form> 
</div>
<div id="footer">

</div>
```

Is it possible to load the code.php after the user clicks submit into the #content div?

Essentially, what I want is when the user clicks the submit button, the code.php after processing is loaded onto the same #content div.

So let say in my code.php, after processing the inputted data, I come up with this lilne of code,

```
<?php
some processing code here;
$name = 'john';
echo $name;
?>
```

So then after hitting submit, user would see

```
<div id="content">
john
</div>
```

Hope I didn't complicate my question by repeating myself, please let me know if this is possible with javascript, php or whatever.

Thanks for the read!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JohnP yes, $.load is a good solution. However, you'll need to send the form data in the request:

**UPDATED [3] for sending a POST with multiple fields and checkboxes:**

```
$('form').submit(function(){

        // create an object to send as a post
        var form = this,
            fields = form.elements,
            el,
            post = {};


        for (var i = fields.length; i--; ) {
            el = fields[i];
            if (el.name) {
                switch (el.type) {
                    case 'checkbox':
                    case 'radio':
                        post[el.name] = (el.checked) ? el.value : '';
                    break;
                    default:
                        post[el.name] = el.value;
                }
            }
        }

    // send the form data in the load request...
    $('#content').load(this.action, post);
    return false;
});
```

This will send the data as a POST.

Comment: Though I only have 1 form tag, i have about 15 input fields with different name values and its breaking the code obviously, I'll try to work with this.

Comment: @usr You can use jquery's `serialize()` method to serialize it and then PHP can unserialize it : http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: @JohnP unfortunately serialize produces a get query.

Comment: @johnhunter no I meant that you can then send it via post to unserialize. If he has that many form fields

Comment: @johnhunter for this, post = { 'name': form.name.value  }; if I were to add a 2nd name value in there, would I just do it with a comma? post = { 'name','age';?

Comment: @JohnP, @usr Maybe I'm confused. I thought he needed a POST request. For load to send a POST it needs an object argument. I have updated the code example above to send all fields in a POST.

Comment: @usr just resolved your multiple fields issue. see updated code.

Comment: Thanks alot both of you @JohnP and @johnhunter, works like a charm :) I placed the above code right after the submit input, just thought I mention it for someone maybe using this in the future.

Comment: Just an added question, for my code.php, along with the name field, I also use value to make my code work. Is it possible to add name as well as the value input and their values into the post? for example I have the mentioned name="name" and value="12".

Comment: @usr, I just updated the post loop to use ordinal index. The post object contains key=>value pairs for each field input that has a name attribute. The http post will contain these key=>value pairs.

Comment: I forgot to mention that some of my form elements are checkboxes as well as input boxes, would that make a difference? Because some of the values in those checkboxes are not getting passed to the php.

Comment: @usr have updated to handle checkboxes. If this doesn't cover all your form fields then perhaps have a look at @Mikk's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've tagged jQuery, I'll use a jQuery example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
       $('#content').load('code.php');
       return false;
    })
})
```

This makes a couple of assumptions here

1. This assumes that code.php is in the same path that you are in now.
2. There is only one form in the page.
3. As @johnhunter points out, this example obviously won't work with post. You can send the post data along with the method. See here for usage : http://api.jquery.com/load

**EDIT**

Here's a fiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/J4Txg/

It replaces the form area with the content from jsfiddle/net/echo/html (which is an empty string).

**NOTE 2** Make sure to include the code in `$(document).ready()` or include it at the bottom of the page. It goes without saying you need jQuery in your page to run this.

Comment: your both assumptions were in my case correct but dosen't seem to load in the div for some reason, just loads code.php when I click submit. I am probably putting the code in the wrong place.

Comment: I've got it loading code.php within the #content div but no 'john', I'd assume it's because I am using the post method and hence no post process is getting done in php?

Comment: Do you get an error? In firefox press `CTRL+SHIFT+J` to open the error console. Clear it of any errors and then run your code and report any errors you may have. Remember to include the above code in `$(document).ready()`!

Comment: Warning: Unexpected token in attribute selector: '!'.
Source File: http://localhost/~john/testing/
Line: 0 - no idea what this means

Comment: Could you paste the JS code you're using in the question? Or paste the entire HTML file in pastebin

Comment: I have some html content in code.php and that loads just not my post processing stuff

Comment: If you're processing depends on $_POST variables, you should look at @johnhunters example and my link to send POST data to your file. Keep in mind that you should only be sending a fragment of HTML and not a full page as that will break your current page

Comment: Have forked your jsfiddle and inserted from my answer. This one works: http://jsfiddle.net/johnhunter/D7XfM/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out jquery form plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#

Answer (score 0):

in simple way use

```
<div id="content">
   if(isset($_POST['submit'] && !empty($_POST) )
   {
      // do your all post process
      $name ='John';
      echo  $name;
   }
   else {
    <form method="POST" action="$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']"> 
        <label for="uname" >Name:</label><input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" size="50">
        <input type=submit value="Get Code" name="submit">
     </form> 
   }
</div>
```